# How should I use 'the,' when referring to 'authors,' 'algorithms,' 'functions' etc.?

Tags: writing-style

If I refer to authors of a publication, a specific algorithm, a specific function etc., do I have to write the definite article *the*?

I'm confused because on the one hand, I refer to concrete authors, a concrete algorithm, or a concrete function. On the other hand, they are, in particular algorithms and functions, proper names, and thus do not require an article. In scientific publications that I've read so far I can spot some inconsistencies in this matter.

Some examples:

1. In [10] X and Y propose a method... *The authors* suggest that... or *Authors* suggest that...
2. *DBSCAN* is an algorithm that... or *The DBSCAN* is an algorithm that...
3. Figure 1.1 shows the values of the distances computed by use of *Euclidean distance*... or *the Euclidean distance*...

Comment: Perhaps ask at https://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @user2768 There is an overlap, but the focus is clearly academia-specific.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper I don't see how English grammar is specific to academia. The question is the same no matter which words the OP is asking about, so it's a better fit for the English Stack.

Comment: @astronat Beyond grammar, permissible language use depends on [pragmatics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragmatics), which is inherently context-specific. The context in this case is academia.

Comment: It's presumably _the authors_ (unless you are referring to _authors_ more generally, e.g., all authors), the other two should be _DBSCAN_ (or _the DBSCAN algorithm_) and _the Euclidean distance_.

Comment: Precise language usage really helps make papers clearer. They are already information dense and often length constrained, so the little things count in accurately conveying meaning from the author to the readers.